# I'm having some trouble parsing data from a csv file to create test runs in Azure DevOps via the REST API using Groovy

Tags: csv, parsing, groovy, azure-devops, azure-devops-rest-api

I'm having some trouble parsing data from a csv file to create test runs in Azure DevOps via the REST API using Groovy.

The csv file is tab delimited because one of the columns (rTestPoints) requires commas for grouping the test points to its test run.

This is the column I'm having trouble with

```
rTestPoints
1754478, 1754479
```

The csv file is formatted as follows:

```
runIds  runNames    runOwners   rTestPoints runStartDate    runCreatedDate  runCompletedDate    
1463132 NewSuite1 (Manual)  Test Owner  1754478, 1754479    2022-05-27T18:51:12Z    2022-05-27T18:51:12Z    2022-05-27T18:51:13.283Z
```

but when I pass this data to the method to create the test run, the testPoints are getting parsed in the body of the Post call as:

```
"pointIds": [
    "1754478, 1754479"
]
```

which isn't associating the test run to the test point.  **Quotes need to surround both values as in:**

```
    "pointIds": [
    "1754478", "1754479"
]
```

}

I tried adding quotes to the csv input file but it results in:

```
 "pointIds": [
        "\"1754478\", \"1754479\""
    ]
```

Any ideas on how I can parse this data correctly by surrounding both values with quotes?

I'm sure there's something I can do to handle this.

Thanks!

Also here's some snippets of the code I'm using.

Here's how I've designed the csv file:

```
def csvdata = []
def columns = ['runIds','runNames', 'runOwners', 'rTestPoints', 'runStartDate', 'runCreatedDate', 'runCompletedDate']
BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(fileName))
br.readLine(); // consume first line and ignore
br.splitEachLine("  ") {values ->
    csvdata.add([columns, values].transpose().collectEntries())
}
```

here's the block of code where I'm passing in the data from csv

```
for (int i=0; i <csvdata.size(); i++) {
                
                String runIds = csvdata.runIds[i]
                String runName = csvdata.runNames[i]
                String runOwner = csvdata.runOwners[i]
                String rTestPoints = csvdata.rTestPoints[i] 
                String runState = "InProgress"
                String runStartDate = csvdata.runStartDate[i]
                String runCreateDate = csvdata.runCreatedDate[i]
                String runCompletedDate = csvdata.runCompletedDate[i]
                String comment = "test run copied from project ${srcproject} and test plan ${srcPlanId} from runID: ${runIds}"
    
            try {
                
                createTestRun = testManagementService.createTestRun(collection, targetProject, targetTestPlanId, rTestPoints, comment, runOwner, runName, runState, runCreateDate, runStartDate, runCompletedDate)
            } catch (e) {
            log.error("Unable to create test run ${runIds} for test point(s) ${rTestPoints} in project: ${targetProject}")
            }
```

Here's the method in the TestManagementService to create the 'test run'

```
public def createTestRun(collection, project, testplanId, testpointIds, comment, owner, name, state, createdDate, startedDate, completedDate) {
                        
            def eproject = URLEncoder.encode(project, 'utf-8')
            eproject = eproject.replace('+', '%20')
            
            def uri = "${genericRestClient.getTfsUrl()}/${collection}/${eproject}/_apis/test/runs?api-version=6.0&bypassRules=True&suppressNotifications=true"
            def body = ['name': name, 'state': state, 'comment': comment, 'createdDate': createdDate, 'starteDate': startedDate, 'completedDate': completedDate, 'owner': [ 'displayName': owner], 'plan': [ 'id': testplanId], 'pointIds': [ testpointIds ] ]
            
            String sbody = new JsonBuilder(body).toPrettyString()
            def result = genericRestClient.rateLimitPost(
                          
                requestContentType: ContentType.JSON,
                contentType: ContentType.JSON,
                uri: uri,
                body: sbody,
                //headers: [Accept: 'application/json'],
                query: ['api-version': '5.1-preview.1' ]
                )
            return result
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

What I had to do was pass instead of passing the rTestPoints as a string, I had to pass it as a "List"

```
            String rTestPoints = csvdata.rTestPoints[i]
            List<String> rTestPointsList = rTestPoints.split(',') as List
```

Then pass rTestPointsList to the createTestRun method

```
createTestRun = testManagementService.createTestRun(collection, targetProject, targetTestPlanId, **rTestPointsList**, comment, runOwner, runName, runState, runCreateDate, runStartDate, runCompletedDate)
```